# What are the odds of losing a bet 10 times in a row when I have a 25% chance of winning?

Tags: probability, gambling

I have been looking for an online calculator to solve the below 2 mathematical problems, but I haven't yet found such a calculator. Thus, can someone answer these questions for me?

1. What are the odds of losing a bet 10 times in a row when I have a 25% chance of winning?
2. What are the odds of losing a bet 20 times in a row when I have a 25% chance of winning?

edit: I mistakenly forgot to mention that I would like the reply answer to be in  the equation of "1 in 1000" or "1 in 12,448" (or whatever the real answer is). I apologize for forgetting this important part.

I will appreciate any help I can get with the above 2 math questions.

Comment: Ten:

$$(1-0.25)^{10} = 0.75^{10} \approx 0.0563 = \boxed{5.63\%}$$

How would you do twenty, given this?

Comment: The [Stattrek binomial calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) is such a calculator

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I really like the answer to be in the equation such as: "1 in 1000 chance" or "1 in 74,226 chance" (or whatever the answer is).

Comment: $5.63\%$ is equivalent to "5.63 in 100 chance" then dividing this ratio by $5.63$ on both sides gives you a "1 in 17.76 chance" or, rounding to the nearest integer a "1 in 18 chance". Try doing it for the 20 games now using the same method as I did.

Answer (score 1):

First part:

Probability of losing 10 times in a row = $(1-0.25)^{10} = (0.75)^{10}$

$$\text{odds} = \frac{\text{favorable outcome}}{\text{unfavorable outcome}}$$

Here the probability of losing $10$ times in a row is favorable outcome, so

$\text{odds} = \frac{0.75^{10}}{1-0.75^{10}}$

Similarly, for second part:

$\text{odds} = \frac{0.75^{20}}{1-0.75^{20}}$

Comment: Sagar Chand, I have to admit I only understand very basic math. Thus, I do not understand the equations you have given. What I really like is for you (or anyone else) give an answer such as: "With a 25% chance of winning, your chances of losing 10 in a row is 1 in 35,782"  (or whatever the real answer is). And the same applies to my question about losing 20 in a row with a 25% chance of winning.

Comment: probability of losing once is 0.75,so probability of losing 2 times is 0.75*0.75. Similarly proba of losing 10 times in a row is $0.75^{10}$
Is this clear?

Comment: But can you can you specifically tell me if it is "1 in 1000 chance" or "1 in 25,837 chance" or whatever?

Comment: 1 in $\frac{1}{0.75^{10}}$ chance for part a